# Select node by text of children

Tags: selenium, testing, xpath, automated-tests

I want to select an element `[@class='title']` with XPath

```
<span class="title">Private Area</span>
<span class="title"><mark>Ablage für Tests</mark></span>
<span class="title">Zweite <mark>Ablage für Tests</mark></span>
```

I need one XPath for all of the three examples where the text can change. I tried `//*[@class='title'][text()='TEXT']`
--> This works only for the first example but not for the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following xpath.Just change the text which you want to fetch.

```
"//span[@class='title'][contains(.,'" + TEXT + "')]"
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. What does "." in contains mean, or what is it substituted with?

Comment: Contains '.' will find matching sub-string

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go for:

```
//span[@class='title']/descendant-or-self::*[text()='SOME TEXT']
```

This will find the span element, and then work down the tree looking for an element that has a text node that matches the specified text.

The problem that you have is that in example 2 and 3 the following works for both:

```
//span[@class='title']/descendant-or-self::*[text()='Ablage für Tests']
```

You can work round this with

```
(//span[@class='title']/descendant-or-self::*[text()='Ablage für Tests'])[1]
(//span[@class='title']/descendant-or-self::*[text()='Ablage für Tests'])[2]
```

Remember the text node belongs to a specific element, `text()` is not the text of a group of elements.

Also I'm not clear which element you are trying to find, The assumption with the above is that you want the element that contains the specified text.  If instead you were looking for the span element you could modify the XPath to:

```
//span[@class='title'][descendant-or-self::*[text()='SOME TEXT']]
```

Comment: => is this correct, can we use `'/'` with `tagName` or method inside square brackets `[/descendant-or-self::*[text()='SOME TEXT']]`

Comment: Sorry typo, you can use it, but it shouldn't have been in that example

Comment: So I can't have one XPath like var path =  "//*[@class='title'][text()='" + TEXT + "']"; where I just change the text?

Comment: Well you could switch `text()` to `.` in the above examples, but then you are going to potentially collect a lot more elements since you are no longer examining a text() node but the string value of an element.  This means that you could be pulling out a series of parent nodes as well as the intended node because they will all have the same String value.